# conditional probability of dependent events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

I posted another question earlier but i can't modify it so please bare with me.

I have a problem where i need to find it's conditional probability: probability of Pc(B)=(B|C) where the event of B={no two people are born in the same month} and event C={exactly three people were born in the summer of june, july august} and there are 9 people involved.

These events are dependents so Pc(B)=P(B|C)=P(B intersection C)/P(C)

I got $P(B)=\frac 1{12} \frac 1{11} \frac 1{10} \frac 19 \frac18 \frac17 \frac 16 \frac 15 \frac 14 =\frac 1{79833600}$

$P(C)=\binom 9  3 \left(\frac 3{12}\right)^3\left(\frac 9{12}\right)^6=\frac{15309}{65536}$

Pc(B)=P(B intersection C)/P(C) where P(B intersection C) = (P(B)*P(C|B)). The thing is how do i find P(C|B)? This is still dependent so i feel like i'm right back to where i started. I saw examples talking about aces where a person draws an ace and doesn't put it back(this is event A) so we have 4/54 and then drawing another ace(this is event B) would be 3/53 so P(B|A) is 3/53... this is simple but in my case i can find the way to do it.

Comment: Why not just compute $\mathbb{P}(B\cap C)$ directly? You're looking for the probability that no two people were born in the same month and that a person was born in each of the three summer months. That shouldn't be too hard to compute.

Comment: Please tell me how then. If they are dependent i can't just do P(B)*P(C) to figure it out, i have to use P(B)*P(C|B) and i have no idea how to get P(C|B) because it is dependent. I don't know how to  just compute it.

Comment: I'll answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compute $\mathbb{P}(B\cap C)$ by counting. There are $12^9$ ways that each person could be assigned a birthday month. Presumably, we are assuming these events are equiprobable. Now how many of these events fall in $B\cap C$? Well, first choose the person born in June (there are 9 possible choices), then the person born in July (8 possibilities), then the one in August (7 possibilities). There are now 6 people left and 9 months with no one yet assigned. Choose the month for the first of these remaining 6 (9 possibilities), then the next (8 possibilities), etc. That last of these remaining 6 will have 4 months to choose from. So multiplying all the possibilities in all the decisions, we end up with $9\cdot 8\cdot 7 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4$.

Clear enough?

Comment: oh! makes total sense now. Thank you. I do have one more question though. I've seen that we can check whether two events are dependent or independent based on whether (((P(B)*P(C))/P(C))=P(B) but i don't understand how that works because won't that always come out to be true? In my question above it is true so i was under the impression that the conditional probability was independent. I can see though by reading the events that it isn't. If the events are really confusing i might not be able to tell whether they are independent or dependent. I really want to know how to work the equation.

Comment: Yeah. That's just wrong. Two events are independent, by definition, if $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) = \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)$.

Comment: So upvote, mark correct, and move to the next problem?

Comment: really? but i thought that if (((P(B)*P(C))/P(C))=P(B) it means that B and C are independent of each other because the result of dividing by either P(B) or P(C) will yield the other.
http://www.cs.uni.edu/~campbell/stat/prob4.html
under independent it says that.. and my prof did the same thing as well to check: "You can check if Pc(B) = P(B)." is what he said.

From what i understood P(A intersection B)=P(A)*P(B) has to do with the probability while (((P(B)*P(C))/P(C))=P(B) has to do with the conditional probability.

Comment: You certainly have to banish from your mind the idea that $\mathbb{P}(B)\mathbb{P}(C)/\mathbb{P}(C) = \mathbb{P}(B)$ means $B$ and $C$ are independent. That's an absurd statement, because it would always hold. The idea of independence would then be trivial. And it isn't. The most basic ways of checking independence are exactly checking $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)$ and checking $\mathbb{P}(A|B)=\mathbb{P}(A)$. Think of this later statement. The probability of $A$ doesn't change if you know $B$. Isn't it then natural to call $A$ and $B$ "independent"?

Comment: makes sense, thank you